# Find the number of solutions of this inequation

Tags: combinatorics

Given any positive integer $n$, is it possible to find the number $N(n)$ of solutions $\{i,j\}$ being $i$ and $j$ positive integers satisfiying the next inequations?

$n^2 < i^2+j^2 < n^2 + 2(i+j-1)$

If NOT, is it possible to have a guess of this number?

In other words:
Given a partition of a square into $2n$ rows and $2n$ columns of same size and suppose there is a circle inscribed in the square, then $4·N(n)$, where $N(n)$ is the number stated above, is the number of squares intersected by the circle within the square.

Comment: Isn't it $4(n-1)$ since the squares in the top-left quadrant are in a sequence that only goes up or right and so has the same number of squares as the sequence that goes on the border of the large square?

Comment: Oh minus the number of pythagorean triples corresponding to the places where the circle passes through a grid intersection.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? Thank you.

Comment: I don't have time to write a nice complete answer. Just follow the circle in the top-left quadrant and take note of the path of squares it cuts. The next square is always above or to the right, unless it goes through a grid intersection. Count the total number of times it goes up and the number of times it goes right. If it goes through a grid intersection, it must correspond to some pythagorean triple. I don't think there is any closed formula for number of pythagorean triples but surely it is asymptotically less than the number of cut squares.